# How can I convert frame count to hh:mm:ss:msec format in Python?

Tags: python

How can I convert frame count values to hh:mm:ss.msec format in Python when video is running at 24 fps.

Comment: Show us what you done.

Comment: By writing a program ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a `datetime.timedelta` object instantiated with the number of seconds, the number of seconds being the number of frames divided by the frames per second.

```
from datetime import timedelta

FPS = 24.0
frame_count = 12345
td = timedelta(seconds=(frame_count / FPS))

>>> print td
0:08:34.375000
```

Comment: Thanks, it is the perfect solution of my problem.